# Чтение и вывод на экран содержимое файла

Tags: файлы, java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class prints{
  public static vois main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    FileReader fin = new Filereader("/root/2/Files.txt"));
    String name;
    int c;
    System.out.println("Print File Files.txt? y/n");
    name = br.readLine();
    if(name.equals("y"))
    while ((c = fin.read()) != -1) System.out.println((char) c);
  }
}
```

Есть запрос, вывести ли содержимое файла на экран, если "y" то вывод.

Comment: JDK 1.6.0
linux

Comment: не просто число а первая строчка файла, выведи в цикле все остальные

Comment: Содержимое файла Files.txt "START" вывод на экран получается 83.

Comment: а что такое fin.read() ?

Comment: `fin.read()` это чтение 1-го символа в виде `int` поэтому и выводится как целое число. Надо прочитать файл целиком в виде `Reader` и выкинуть на печать

Comment: Какбэ все процедуры буферного чтения возвращают количество прочитанных байт... Это чуть ли не 72м кегелем во всех документациях написано.

Comment: тогда какой функцией вывести данные с файла?

Comment: import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class prints{
      public static vois main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        FileReader fin = new Filereader("/root/2/Files.txt"));
        String name;
        int c;
        System.out.println("Print File Files.txt? y/n");
        name = br.readLine();
        if(name.equals("y"))
        while ((c = fin.read()) != -1) System.out.println((char) c);
      } }
Вывод осуществляется,как отдельный символ на каждой строке.Как исправить на строчный?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вам требуется вывести текст файла в консоль, то лучше выводить его построчно через BufferedReader.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileRead{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        File f = new File("/root/2/Files.txt");
        BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String name;
        String line;
        System.out.println("Print File "+f.getName()+"? y/n");
        name = br.readLine();
        if(name.equals("y"))
        while ((line = fin.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё прекрасно работает!

Comment: Как мне доставляет принцип блочного копирования в программировании... Прелесно!

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
Byte[] infile;
file.read(infile[]);
System.out.print(infile[]);
```

Comment: Вот вот так работает?

Comment: Нет не будет потому вы читаете как массив байтов :)

Comment: Нет, при компиляции
prints.java:10: '.class' expected
fin.read(infile[]);
                 ^
prints.java:11: '.class' expected
System.out.println(infile[]);
                           ^
2 errors

Содержимое файла String наверно.

Comment: Если не System.out.println(fin.read()); а System.out.println(fin); то выводится 
java.io.FileInputStream@a90653

Comment: @Barmaley дык вроде любой текст это и есть массив байтов. "Текст" - это байты, отвечающие за "Т", "е", "к", "с" и "т"

Comment: Тогда так: 

    FileReader file = new FileReader("text.txt");
char[] buf;
file.read(buf);
System.out.println(buf);

Comment: prints.java:10 : variable buf might not have been initialized
fin.read(buf);
         ^

Comment: @danpetruk в Java текст это 2 байта (`char`), надо выкидывать на печать в виде `char`, а вы кидаете `byte`, который отображается в виде целого значения.

Comment: FileReader file = new FileReader("text.txt");
char[] buf = {};
file.read(buf);
System.out.println(buf);

Comment: Всё откомпилированно, но содержимое файла не отображается при печати, выдаёт пустую строчку.